# Duplicate updates while doing mongo update

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Please find below the script to update the fields in a collection

```
var limit = 500000;
var sourcecollections = db.sourcecollection.find().limit(limit);
sourcecollections.forEach(function(sourcecollection) {

log('Updating ');
db.sourcecollection.update({_id: sourcecollection._id}, {$set : {'ext.index': '.' + sourcecollection.ext.index, 'ext.value': '.' +sourcecollection.ext.value}});

});
```

The problem here is the update happening multiple times to each record, looks like looping more than one time in the foreach.

Any clues ?

Thanks,
Prats

Comment: Why do you think it's happening multiple times to the same record?

Comment: This looks like it should work.  Can you post the output that led you to believe that there was a problem?

Comment: Its adding more than 1 '.' to the field in several records.If I comment the update statement, number of iterations are correct.

Comment: Do any of the ext.index or ext.value fields have a '.' already when you run the command?